# Vue.js2 renders empty array

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I am using vue.js in my laravel project. The problem is that vue.js is rendering empty array although I an see that the variabel names has some data.

I am using laravel 5.4 and vue.js2. For the jsonp get method I am using vue-resource

Also if I want to see my variable containing data `{{names}}` in the template it just adds an empty array. There are no error logs in both cases.

**template.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    {{names}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Js**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function(){
            return {
              names: []
            };

        },
        methods:  {
         getData: function(){
             var self = this;
              // GET request
           this.$http.jsonp(url, {jsonpCallback: "JSON_CALLBACK"})
           .then(response=>{
               return response.body;              
           })
           .then(data =>{
               self.names = data
                console.log(JSON.stringify(self.names))// logs the data 
           })
        }
      },
       mounted() {
            this.getData()

            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**blade.php**

```
<search id='search'>
</search>
```

**the JSON response looks like this**

```
[
   {
      "uri":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung",
      "id":"24366",
      "type":"org",
      "score":527013,
      "label":{
         "eng":"Samsung"
      }
   },
   {
      "uri":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Electronics",
      "id":"30860",
      "type":"org",
      "score":135216,
      "label":{
         "eng":"Samsung Electronics"
      }
   }
]
```

vue dev tools show the variable 
[image]

Comment: this one logs anything ? console.log(JSON.stringify(self.names), or does it log at all ?

Comment: @John yes this one logs the JSON response. This is why I know that the data is there.

Comment: do you have vue devtools? the names variable shows the results there ?

Comment: @John yes it does see the image above

Comment: your template and component script are in the same file yes?

Comment: the component initiates into another file app.js like this Vue.component('search', require('./components/Searchnames.vue')); not sure if this does actully initiates the component, but the data, methods and mounted properties are indeed within the same file

Comment: Just to be sure: what you have shown in your *template.vue* section and your *Js* section are in the same file?

Comment: try $vm.$forceUpdate() in console and see if that renders the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, i am not quite sure why but the issue was because i had initiated my component as this

```
Vue.component('search', require('./components/Searchnames.vue'));

const search = new Vue({
    el: '#search'
});
```

then in a different file I referenced data and method functions via export default, this caused the issue, removing

```
const search = new Vue({
    el: '#search'
});
```

solves the problem. not sure why that is though,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but I put your code together into a runnable snippet, and it works as expected. Obviously I replaced your data request.

It sounds like `self` is somehow not what you think it is when you do the assignment. I do not know how that would happen, though.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#search',
  components: {
    search: {
      data: function() {
        return {
          names: []
        };

      },
      methods: {
        getData: function() {
          const self = this;

          setTimeout(function () {
            self.names = [{
                "uri": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung",
                "id": "24366",
                "type": "org",
                "score": 527013,
                "label": {
                  "eng": "Samsung"
                }
              },
              {
                "uri": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Electronics",
                "id": "30860",
                "type": "org",
                "score": 135216,
                "label": {
                  "eng": "Samsung Electronics"
                }
              }
            ];
          }, 0);

        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.getData()

        console.log('Component mounted. names is', this.names);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<search id='search' inline-template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            {{names}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</search>
```

Comment: Thank you, thsi did not solve the problem but I did get one hint. when I log this.names from the mounted function I get something like this

[ob: Observer] 0 : Array(20) //this is the data length : 1 ob : Observer proto : Array

This could be the reason that because of this [ob: Observer] I do not get the data

Comment: The Observer is what Vue puts in to make the object reactive.

Comment: yes but I think this is what is causing the problem, I do not know how to slve it though

Comment: this.names.length returns 0 but  [ob: Observer] 0 : Array(20) means that the array is there just it can not be iterated

Comment: In the `mounted` function, the array should not have been populated yet. You call `getData`, which does an asynchronous call. I notice you provide a `jsonpCallback`; what do you have that doing?

Comment: jsonpCallback is the callback inside the API. The data is enclosed in a function